# How do I call the Activity to start again?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am creating a quiz to practice Android programming. I am able to run the Android program and it works fine. But now, I have added a `ContextMenu`. If I click any item, the Activity should restart with a new value. But it does not.

```
TextView Qsn;
Button TopicTitle;
Button Ybtn;
Button Nbtn;
String check;   

@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.history);
    Qsn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Question);
    TopicTitle = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Topictxt);
    Ybtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Yesbtn);
    Nbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Nobtn);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle =intent.getExtras();
    check=bundle.getString("Bundlekey") ;
    TopicTitle.setText(check);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), check, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)  .show();    
    registerForContextMenu(TopicTitle);
    if (check.matches("History")) {
        ....
    }
}
```

The code check what topic has been selected and it works fine till here. But now I've added a `ContextMenu` so if the user wants to change the topic he can long-press on the button and select the topic and change his new topic for a new question.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.topic_selection_in_question, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    String Value_from_item ;         
    Value_from_item = (String) item.getTitle();     
    check = Value_from_item;
    Intent intent = getIntent(); finish(); startActivity(intent);
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Where did I make the mistake? Is there an error in the logic? I do not get a runtime error. Everything works fine. I would be glad if you can help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this code

```
Intent intent = getIntent(); finish(); startActivity(intent);
```

Use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(youractivity.this, Youractivity.class);
 finish(); 
startActivity(intent);
```